# I want the tokenized sentences along with their positions

Tags: python

The end result should be a dictionary in which the keys are the names of your texts and the values are lists of lists. Each embedded list should be a sentence, tokenized into words.

The dictionary should therefore look something like this:
{'Text1 Name':[['this', 'is', 'sentence', '1'], ['this', 'is', 'sentence', '2'], ...],
'Text2 Name': [['this', 'is', 'sentence', '1'], ['this', 'is', 'sentence', '2'], ...],
...}

I want the output to print its position along with the sentences.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
sent_tokenize(text)
I have converted the text into sentences but i need it in the above form.

op:
```

['The Project Gutenberg EBook of On the Origin of Species, by Charles Darwin\r\n\r\nThis eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with\r\nalmost no restrictions whatsoever.',
'You may copy it, give it away or\r\nre-use it under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included\r\nwith this eBook or online at www.gutenberg.org\r\n\r\n** This is a COPYRIGHTED Project Gutenberg eBook, Details Below **\r\n**     Please follow the copyright guidelines in this file.',
'**\r\n\r\nTitle: On the Origin of Species\r\n\r\nAuthor: Charles Darwin\r\n\r\nPosting Date: May 7, 2011 [EBook #8205]\r\nRelease Date: June, 2005\r\nFirst Posted: July 2, 2003\r\n\r\nLanguage: English\r\n\r\nCharacter set encoding: ASCII\r\n\r\n*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK ON THE ORIGIN OF SPECIES ***\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nProduced by Steve Eccles\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nOn the Origin of Species\r\n\r\nby Charles Darwin\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nAudio production Copyright (C) 2003 by Steve Eccles\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nThis copyrighted audio performance is based on Project Gutenberg's\r\npublic domain eBook, "On the Origin of Species."',
'This file is for the Identification of the maker of this CD ROM Audio,\r\nComputer Read, Book: "On the Origin of Species" by Charles Darwin.',
'CD ROM: Completed on the 4th of April, 2003.',

Comment: looks like a valid question, but not formatted properly...  please reformat to this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please read about [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Where do strings `'Text1 Name'` etc come from? What do you mean by "positions" in your title? Is `[word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(text)]` close to what you want? (The text may need to be cleaned up; sentence tokeniser doesn't treat newlines as sentence breaks.)